# Numerical evaluation of the expected value

Tags: numerical-methods, expected-value, means

I'd like to know if it's correct to numerically evaluate the expected value in this way, and, if yes, why it's right.
I have a discrete random variable $X$ with a binomial distribution, the discrete density is a vector $densità$ and the values of $X$ are in the vector $x$. The numerical mean:

$$
mean = \sum _{i} x_i \, densità_i
$$

I found this formula in the handout of my professor and it's quite strange the presence of the density, I was expected the probability (definition of the expected value for a discrete random variable):

$$
mean = \sum _{x \in \mathbb{R}} x \, P(X = x)
$$

Comment: The 'densitia' (as you call it) is usually called the mass function, and by your notation $\textit{densita}_i=P(X=x_i)$. 

Note you need to be careful in what you write, ask yourself two questions : in your first sum what values does $i$ take, in your second sum is there any meaning to  $\sum_{x\in \mathbb{R}}$ ? Moreover, I wouldn't call this a numerical evaluation of the expected value...

Comment: Hello Daniel the second sum is a definition, so it's not related to what I said before. The densità vector was created in RStudio with the command dbinom()

Comment: In your second definition you don't need an uncountable sum.

Comment: @DanielAdams it's the definition given by my prof

Comment: Tell him its unnecessary since a discrete random variable is one which may take on only a countable number of distinct values.

Comment: And as I said a discrete density is usually called a mass function. Now google mass function, and discrete random variable and expected value, and it will all make sense. Or give us your understanding/definition of $\textit{densita}_i$ which I bet you is just $P(X=x_i)$.

Comment: ok thank you @DanielAdams I'll check

Comment: It may interest you to know that the general definition of the expected value of $X$ (whether $X$ is discrete or not) is $\int X$, where the integration is with respect to the probability measure. In case, $X$ is discrete, this is equal to $\sum xP(X=x)$.

Comment: This is evaluation of mean on base of the "Law of the unconscious statistician". Have a look at [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician). As @Shahab remarks: it is not the definition. For that we have:$$\mathbb EX=\int X(\omega)P(d\omega)$$An integration in the underlying probability space.

Comment: @DanielAdams yes $P(X=x_i)$ is the discrete density (mass function). Thank you for your help